# SQL: How to do filtering with where using a self reference

Tags: mysql, sql

This is my SQL code.

```
SELECT 
    wpp.ID, wpp.post_title, wpp.guid,
    (SELECT guid FROM wp_posts  
     WHERE post_parent = (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts 
                          WHERE post_title ="Writer Thumbnail Image "+wpp.ID )) AS imgID 
FROM 
    `wp_posts` AS wpp  
WHERE 
    wpp.post_status = "publish" 
    AND wpp.post_type = "post"  
ORDER BY 
    wpp.ID DESC 
LIMIT 4
```

I want where like (WHERE post_title ="Writer Thumbnail Image 251") But this number take from wpp.ID

How can I do this?

Comment: Which database? `+` works on some, others require `||`, or the function `CONCAT`... SQL dialects are wildly different, always also tag with the exact dialect you are using besides the generic [tag:sql].

Comment: @Amadan String concatenation is with || in standard SQL. So use || and it should work.

Comment: @frlan: `<sarcasm>` Yes, that works beautifully [in MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/logical-operators.html#operator_or). `</sarcasm>` "SQL standard"... (`SELECT 'A' || 'B'` is `0`, not `'AB'` like `SELECT CONCAT('A', 'B')`)

Comment: Hmmm. Was not aware of this. Sorry. Maybe we should start considering MySQL not calling SQL anymore...

Answer (score 1):

It appears that you are using `MySQL`. In this case you may use:

```
 SELECT wpp.ID,wpp.post_title,wpp.guid,parent.guid as imgID
 from wp_posts as wpp inner join wp_posts as parent
 on wpp.post_parent =parent.ID
WHERE wpp.post_status = "publish" 
AND wpp.post_type = "post" 
and  wpp.post_title = CONCAT("Writer Thumbnail Image ",parent.ID)
ORDER BY wpp.ID DESC LIMIT 4
```

I am not sure if your want:

```
 and  wpp.post_title = CONCAT("Writer Thumbnail Image ",parent.ID)
```

or

```
 and  parent.post_title = CONCAT("Writer Thumbnail Image ",parent.ID)
```

or

```
and  wpp.post_title = CONCAT("Writer Thumbnail Image ",wpp.ID)
```

use whichever that suits your problem

Comment: thx. But itn't work.I try to change (post_title ="Writer Thumbnail Image "+wpp.ID) to (post_title =CONCAT("Writer Thumbnail Image ",wpp.ID)) ,It's work. thx for your ex.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT wpp.ID,wpp.post_title,wpp.guid,
(SELECT guid FROM wp_posts  WHERE post_parent = (SELECT ID FROM wp_posts WHERE post_title =CONCAT("Writer Thumbnail Image ",wpp.ID) )) AS imgID 
FROM `wp_posts` AS wpp  WHERE wpp.post_status = "publish" AND wpp.post_type = "post"  ORDER BY wpp.ID DESC LIMIT 4
```

this is final code.That work.

change

```
WHERE post_title ="Writer Thumbnail Image "+wpp.ID
```

To

```
WHERE post_title =CONCAT("Writer Thumbnail Image ",wpp.ID)
```